# VSC compile LaTeX without linking positions on code tab and PDF tab

Tags: latex

I am facing when compiling Latex file, the window show PDF files always show the first page, it is better if it shows the editing page PDF. How to solve this problem?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lt2dH.png)

Comment: (completely unrelated to the problem, but the `Partial` after the comma should be small)

Comment: If you are not too attached to your editor, you could have a look at texstudio. This will automatically focus the pdf on the part you are currently working on (if compiled with synctex enabled)